# Facebook/Bit.ly can't read meta tags

Tags: facebook, wordpress

All of a sudden, Facebook sharing has stopped working on my site. It's been working smoothly for the past six months, whereby FB correctly displays page title, image and description, but it suddenly can't access the meta tags.

Furthermore, bit.ly can't read the page title either. I can't see any reason why this would happen and I'm fairly certain I've not made any changes that would cause this to happen.

Here is an example:

http://www.newsatden.co.uk/3853-millwall-target-montgomery-can-leave-sheffield-united-for-free.html

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

The FB debugger says when it attempts to crawl the page, the following is returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> --><html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0.1">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body><p></p></body>
</html>
```

None of that code is in my headers, so I'm really stumped.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your URL through the debugger, Facebook tells me that there is a 206 response code. The definition of a 206 code is "Partial Content."

It typically means your HTML has errors in it and Facebook's parser is giving up.

My guess is it's coming from an error in the embedded style in your `<head>`. Get this into a separate css file and see if it works better.

You also don't have any open graph meta tags.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I forgot to mention I've been playing around with the meta tags hence why they're not currently there. The problem occurs both when they are there/not there. When you say 'embedded style' what exactly are you referring to? Many thanks

Comment: Look at your source. There is an opening `<style>` tag on line 10 and the closing `</style>` tag is on line 200. This should be in a separate css file like the one in the `<link>` tag on line 9.

Comment: I see what you mean. It does need tidying up a little. However, I'm not convinced this is the issue. I've tried to check the CSS using a validator (http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=www.newsatden.co.uk&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) and it can't even detect a stylesheet! It's as if the server is denying access to all external sites.

Comment: It's not your server that's doing this. It's the validator scripts. They're giving up because something is wrong with your code.

Comment: OK I will try and put all the CSS into separate stylesheets and see if that fixes it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've identified the offending CSS and created a separate stylesheet for it. That seems to have solved the issue.